# Calculating the electric power of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Let the following circuit, I want to calculate the electric power of it, so since I'm quite new to this kind of problem where there is two voltage-source, I will use the superposition approach:

[image]

First, I deactivate the left-most voltage generator 8 V then:
\$ 12 = -4V_1 - 10000i+V_1 \iff -\frac{12+10000i}{3} = V_1\$

Second, I deactivate the right-most voltage generator 12 V then:
\$ 8 = 4V_1 + 10000i - V_1 \iff \frac{8-10000i}{3} = V_1\$

Lastly \$ V_1 = -4(\frac{1+5000i}{3})\$

So up to this point am I correct?

Comment: I'd just like to suggest an independent method to check (validate) whatever you come up with. You have a voltage source that is 4 times the magnitude (but with opposing sign) of the \$4\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor. Since the loop current must everywhere be the same, this implies that the dependent voltage source can be modeled as a \$-16\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor. Two fixed voltage sources are in opposition and can be replaced by just one of \$4\:\text{V}\$ where the \$12\:\text{V}\$ is at, shorting the other.  \$-16\:\text{k}\Omega+4\:\text{k}\Omega+10\:\text{k}\Omega=-2\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

Comment: So, given the \$4\:\text{V}\$ source and a single \$-2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor across it to [form a loop to the left of the voltage source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbZCg.png), the resulting loop current should be \$2\:\text{mA}\$ and circulating in the clockwise direction. Use this as a check against your own processes in solving this problem.

Comment: @periblepsis why / how did you replace the the opposing voltage-sources with 4 volts source? also you said \$ 4V_1 = 4*(R*(-i)) = -4*4i = -16 k\Omega *i \$

Comment: All of your two-terminal devices are in a single, shared loop. So all of them are effectively in series with each other. Voltage sources in a loop either add or subtract from each other in cases like this. Since the +12 V source is oppositely posed against the +8 V source, and they are in series, the two can be combined into the dominant +8 V source. The dependent source is entirely dependent upon a resistor's voltage drop, except oppositely polarized. So it must, in effect, be a negative resistor. Resistors in series can be simply added up and replaced by a single resistor. Simple as that.

Comment: `Since the +12 V source is oppositely posed against the +8 V source, and they are in series, the two can be combined into the dominant +8 V source.` you mean a -4V source? because they are opposed and taking a clockwise current sign we have the dominant voltage source to be (8-12)V, no?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry about that. I mean a +4 source where the +12 V source is currently located. As I showed in my diagram.

Comment: @periblepsis ah so you take a counter clockwise current sign? it would be the same if we take a clockwise sign and replace it in the +8V source?

Comment: It's not important. What is important is that you remain consistent in your approach. You can just as well replace the +8 V source with -4 V source. Doesn't matter to me.

Comment: @periblepsis thank you so much , but could you look at my superposition approach?

Comment: No. It has a dependent source and this would complicate my writing. If I go that far, I may as well write an answer. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: ah does a dependent-source need to be deactived when using superposition?

Comment: There are ways to avoid superposition. I could write about that, too. But all this starts to become a serious answer, which I'm really trying to avoid doing.

Comment: aight thank you for your effort appreciated

Comment: If you really want, I can write it up. But I'm hoping you don't need it. If you do, though, I will proceed.

Comment: @periblepsis i wont say no to such offer to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by picking a ground:

[image]

We can redraw this as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frF0Hu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the conventional current is clockwise in your circuit. Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: last question is the voltage of V_1 negative so if we go by the last scheme : \$V_1 = -Ri = -8V \$