# Calculating the electrical power of this circuit

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

In my question, I have successfully calculated the current of the circuit and the voltage , \$ I =-2 mA , V_1 = -32 V \$ [Calculating the electric power of this circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/680443/348371)
But I’m confused in calculating the electrical power of the whole circuit, so the resistances, \$P_{10 k \Omega} = 0.04 W, P_{4 k \Omega} = 0.016 W\$
and here comes the big confusion for the sources:

\$ P_{8 V} = 8 * I = -0.016 \$

\$ P_{12 V} = - 12 * I = 0.024 W ?!\$

\$P_{4V_1} = -4*V_1 * I = -0.064 W \$

somehow this sums up to zero, but why is the electrical power of an independent source positive?!

Here is the schematic: [image]

Comment: Please post a schematic.

Comment: ah okey i thought it was like in the other SE post? @winny

Comment: If same schematic, just copy the link to the image and paste it online here. The image, not the link.

Comment: Where is the problem? Two resistors dissipate 56mW together. The independent voltage source together with VCVS supplies provides energy into the circuit -16mW + (-64mW) = -80mW. And the remaining independent voltage source (12V) dissipates power (24mW) (absorbing power). This means that we are "charging" the 12V source. Just as you charge your smartphone battery. So we have -80mW = 56mW+24mW Everything is correct.

Comment: @G36 coming in the clutch again, infinite thanks! also you agree with my value of the intensity \$ I = -2mA \$?

Comment: Notice that you have marked the current direction on your schematic in a clockwise direction. But then you have written I = -2mA  which means that the "real current" is flowing in counter-clockwise. Which is not true for this circuit. Because for this circuit the "real current" is flowing in a clockwise direction. So, on the schematic, it should have been marked I = 2mA.

Comment: i really dont get your argument when you said the "real current is flowing in clockwise direction"? @G36

Comment: You have marked the current direction on the circuit diagram but you wrongly label it. The correct labeling should be I = 2mA.

Comment: one way to look at it : the 12 V battery is charging (after i calculated the power) so its impossible for it at that moment of charging so produce a positive current @G36

Comment: Ok, never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simulation with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

Adding "powers" ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The phrase “power of a circuit” has no meaning. Voltage and current sources are commonly called power sources or power supplies.

The other elements in a circuit either store or dissipate power.

The sum of power supplied must equal the sum of stored and dissipated.

Generally power supplied is considered negative, power stored and dissipated is considered positive. So then the sum equals zero, as was observed.

This is called conservation of energy.

> \$ P_{12 V} = - 12 * I = 0.024 W ?!\$

||Before I answer this, the negative current means that the current in the circuit is actually clockwise.||

The power in the resistors is based on \$P=I^2R\$, so will always be positive regardless of the current direction.

Either way some of the sources may be charging as if they were a battery. In this case the 8V source is charging because the actual current is in the counter-clockwise direction. If the power is positive then the source is being charged.

Note: Sources do not dissipate power. They supply power or store energy

Comment: yes but i found that the power dissipated by the 12 V power source is positive thats crazy

Comment: @Mohamed you’ve missed a minus sign, the power is in fact negative, so the source is supplying power, as you would expect.  -12 * I = -0.024W

Comment: then sum up all the powers you wont get zero @Frog

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI current is equal to ...  I= 2 mA ...

Comment: no i found its -2 mA @Antonio51